# inline ARMv7-M assembly code into c using gcc (Load Register literal)

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly, armv7

I would like to be able to have LDR literal instructions to load registers.

I have:

```c
    extern uint32_t _vStackBase;
    extern uint32_t _vStackTop;

    __asm volatile
    (
        "   mov r10, #0x5a5a5a5a          \n"
        "   ldr r8, %[stackTop]           \n"
        "   ldr r7, %[stackBase]          \n"::
        [stackTop] "r"(&_vStackTop), [stackBase] "r"(&_vStackBase):
        "r7", "r8", "r10"
    );
```

the code produced is:

```
 216 ???? 484B          ldr r3, .L66+8
 217 ???? 494A          ldr r2, .L66+12
 218                    .syntax unified
 219                @ 98 "src/startup/startup.c" 1
 220 ???? 4FF05A3A     mov r10, #0x5a5a5a5a          
 221 ???? 5FF80480     ldr r8, r3           
 222 ???? 5FF80470     ldr r7, r2
```

There are two problems: the compiler unnecessarily uses registers r2 and r3.
The thing I'd like to be able to do is:

```
    ldr r8, .L66+8
    ldr r7, .L66+12
    [...]
```

but I can deal with this inefficiency.

The second and more serious problem is that the assembler gives this error:

```
Error: cannot represent T32_OFFSET_IMM relocation in this object file format
```

how can i get what i want?

**EDIT 2021-10-27**

I tried as suggested by @timoty

```c
    extern uint32_t _vStackBase;
    extern uint32_t _vStackTop;
    __asm volatile
    (
        "   mov r10, #0x5a5a5a5a          \n"
        "   ldr r8, %[stackTop]           \n"
        "   ldr r7, %[stackBase]          \n"::
        [stackTop] "m"(_vStackTop), [stackBase] "m"(_vStackBase):
        "r7", "r8", "r10", "memory"
    );
```

generated code is still wrong:

```
 226 0038 4B4B          ldr r3, .L66+8
 227 003a 4C4A          ldr r2, .L66+12
 228                    .syntax unified
 229                @ 127 "src/startup/startup.c" 1
 230 003c 4FF05A3A         mov r10, #0x5a5a5a5a          
 231 0040 D3F80080     ldr r8, [r3]           
 232 0044 1768         ldr r7, [r2] 

[...]

 701                .L66:
 702 0160 00C00A40      .word   1074446336
 703 0164 A5FAAF5A      .word   1521482405
 704 0168 00000000      .word   _vStackTop
 705 016c 00000000      .word   _vStackBase
```

Again, this is not what I want, and it's also wrong.

Just to give it another try, I made this:

```c
    extern uint32_t *_vStackBase;
    extern uint32_t *_vStackTop;
    __asm volatile
    (
        "   mov r10, #0x5a5a5a5a          \n"
        "   ldr r8, %[stackTop]           \n"
        "   ldr r7, %[stackBase]          \n"::
        [stackTop] "m"(*_vStackTop), [stackBase] "m"(*_vStackBase):
        "r7", "r8", "r10", "memory"
    );
```

again wrong:

```
 225                    .loc 1 127 9 view .LVU59
 226 0038 4B4A          ldr r2, .L66+8
 227 003a 4C4B          ldr r3, .L66+12
 228 003c 1268          ldr r2, [r2]
 229                    .syntax unified
 230                @ 127 "src/startup/startup.c" 1
 231 003e 4FF05A3A         mov r10, #0x5a5a5a5a          
 232 0042 D3F80080     ldr r8, [r3]           
 233 0046 1768         ldr r7, [r2]
```

Comment: If what you want is in r3 (aka %[stackTop]), why not just use that?  Why copy the value from one register to another?  Are you modifying the value?

Comment: Why do you need assembly for that at all ? `"r"(&_vStackTop)`, so that's actually an address in memory, why not to declare it so `extern uint32_t* _vStackTop;` and just dereference pointer into whatever variable you need

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I don't know that r3 contains what I want. It's gcc that can decide. I see it after translating from c to assembly. I only wrote the piece of `__asm volatile` code you see in the post. I'm not the one who wants to copy one register into another.

Comment: @user3124812 In the startup code of a project I have to prefill the main stack, so I can't use the stack itself for variables and function calls. Before this I had written c code using `register` variables, but  gcc can take the liberty of making implicit `memset` calls. Moreover the Storage-class specifiers `register` is just a preference communicated to gcc that remains free to ignore it and place the variables on the stack.
The safest thing I thought was to write the prefill in assembly to be sure that no variable goes on the stack and no function is called.

Comment: It's true that you don't know which register gcc might select, but you don't need to know.  Just keep using %[stackTop].  Unless you're changing the value.  You currently have it defined as an input, and inputs must have the same value upon exiting the asm as they had on entry.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd As I wrote in my post the code I wrote does not compile because of that error: `Error: cannot represent T32_OFFSET_IMM relocation in this object file format`

Comment: You said you had 2 problems and I was helping with the one I could.  I'm no ARM programmer, but T32_OFFSET_IMM suggests that the target doesn't support 32 bit immediates, so is unable to encode the specified instruction.  Looking at the [docs](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/readings/ARMv7-M_ARM.pdf) (page 287) suggests only 8 or 16 bit values are supported (but I may be reading that wrong).  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800055/movw-and-movt-in-arm-assembly) talks about loading 32bit values into a register.  Best I've got for you.

Comment: *Again, this is not what I want, and it's also wrong.* (for your first updated version with `[stackTop] "m"(_vStackTop)`). - But it's *not* wrong.  It's exactly what the compiler would do for reading the value of a global 32-bit variable without inline asm.  First load the address from a nearby literal pool, then load the value.  Since it's `extern`, I think the compiler can't assume that it could put the storage near enough to the code anyway.  Also, it's not `const` so it's definitely not putting read-write variables mixed with code in a literal pool.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/q5f35vo5v shows GCC 11.1 using movw/movt to construct addresses in registers instead of loading from a literal pool.  You say you want `ldr r8, .L66+8`, so why don't you just ask for the address in `r8` in the first place and leave that up to the compiler, instead of trying to use an `ldr` in your own asm statement?  (Use `register uint32_t *r8 asm("r8") = &_vStackTop;` since there's no specific-register constraint for ARM).  If you don't want to load from the address, don't use another `ldr`.

Answer (score 0):

> the compiler unnecessarily uses registers r2 and r3.

That is because you ask for registers here:

```
[stackTop] "r"(&_vStackTop), [stackBase] "r"(&_vStackBase):
```

To request the compiler to provide a memory reference use `"m"`instead of `"r"`.

```
Error: cannot represent T32_OFFSET_IMM relocation in this object file format
```

Since you ask for register the compiler substitutes a register in place of `%[stackTop]` resulting in `ldr r8, r3`. The second operand of an `ldr` instruction is a memory reference and since there is no memory location named `r3` in the file (or it is in another section) the assembler would leave a relocation in the object file for the linker fix, but this not supported by ELF and other object file formats as this not very useful due to the short range of a PC relative memory reference.

Comment: For memory operands, you'd also want to ask for the value in memory, instead of the address in a register.  Like `[stackTop] "m" (_vStackTop)`.  The compiler will substitute an addressing mode that reaches memory holding the value you ask for, so if it's some expression like `&_vStackTop`, it will have to create a local temporary holding that address.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not clear about what you say, but I tried to use `[stackBase] "m"(&_vStackBase)`, but gcc reports an error: `error: memory input 1 is not directly addressable`.

Comment: @mastupristi: Oh right, GCC/clang require an lvalue for `"m"` memory operands, and won't invent a memory location for a temporary result of an expression.  So anyway, like I said you need `[stackTop] "m" (_vStackTop)`, not just changing `"r"` to `"m"`.